# The show of support includes binoculars and bomber jackets

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Thank you for your consistent support. I appreciate it.

I am currently reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/trump-says-could-meet-north-230633974.html), and a paragraph says,

> Every president since Ronald Reagan has visited the 1953 armistice line, except for George H.W. Bush, who visited when he was vice president. **The show of bravado and support for one of America's closest military allies has evolved over the years to include binoculars and bomber jackets.**

Would two words, which are **binoculars and bomber jackets,** in my guess try to imply that since 1953 America's support for allies against North Korea provided (probably huge) military support?

I'm asking this question because these two words (goods) are not substantially big enough to imply military support. (Had they been such as "bombers" or "air defense systems", I would've understood.)

Or would they mean "monitoring and staffs in charge"?

Thank you for analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a photo of [President Obama visiting the Korean DMZ, wearing a bomber jacket.](https://www.cbc.ca/news/world/obama-visits-military-post-near-korean-dmz-1.1210119)

My interpretation would be that the "show of bravado and support" is a visit by the US president to the Korean armistice line. While there, they look through binoculars. The words are literal, they do not "imply" something else.

Comment: I guess there would be no way other than your interpretation.Thanks.